# Kafka Streams application does not log error when broker is not running

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

I am wondering that my Kafka Streams Application does not log anything when the actual broker to which it is connecting is not running. It just keeps running.

```
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "App_ID");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "client_id");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

    StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    streams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder(), properties);
    streams.start();
```

When I shutdown my broker on localhost:9092 nothing happens. Should it now give me a kind of signal that the Kafka Broker is not reachable for the application? Is that maybe a configuration thing?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you share the topology and the topology launching code.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the standard behavior of the underlying `KafkaConsumer` -- it just tries to reconnect but does not signal anything that it cannot reach the brokers. In general, this behavior make the consumer quite robust and KafkaStreams inherits this behavior.

It's unfortunately not straightforward to fix. Cf: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6520